# Negate regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I know, it seems like yet another duplicate question, but I can't make it work.

My pattern `:\d\s"` works fine, but when I'm trying to add negation to find lines that do not contain the above regex, n++ doesn't find any. I've tried `(?!:\d\s")`, with different variations of wild cards, to no avail.

Sample data:

`blah_blah:0 "More blah..."`

`blah_blah:0 More blah..."`

(space at the beginning and `\n` at the end of the lines).

I want to be able to catch missing quote for example (see the second line).

**UPD**: I need to invert my regex to find incorrectly formatted lines.

Comment: Sample data you want to match, along with s amele data that should not xmatch,, would be helpful.

Comment: I know, `:\d\s\w` will work, but it'll be good to know other ways.

Comment: Include these lines `"I'm trying to add negation to find lines that do not contain the above regex"`

Comment: Use your regex in *Mark* tab (just check the *Bookmark line* option) and after clicking *Mark All*, click *Search* -> *Boomark* -> *Inverse Bookmark*.

Comment: If it is not working for you, please precise what you are doing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it worked. I was looking for a regex with the same functionality though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your `:\d\s"` regex in *Mark* tab (just check the *Bookmark line* option) and after clicking *Mark All*, click *Search* -> *Bookmark* -> *Inverse Bookmark*.

If you want a regex way of solving this task, you need to use

```
^(?!.*:\d\s").+
```

This regex will highlight any non-empty line has no match for the `:\d\s"` pattern.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!.*:\d\s")` - that has no `:`, digit, whitespace and `"` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.+`  - any 1 or more chars other than line break chars

[image]

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `^` matching the beginning of a new line in certain text editors like Notepad++. It usually is however the start of the string.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: Yes, actually, anchors and word boundaries work in a very peculiar way  in NPP. Just for fun, try `\A\w` --> `\($&\)` on any document with *Replace All*.

Comment: I have not mentioned any options that should be enabled. So, *`.` matches newline* must be disabled, as it is by default.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it works but with the box unchecked though, same as in ssc-hrep's answer.

Comment: I added the screenshot with the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression:

```
(?:^|\r?\n)(?!.*?:\d\s.*?).*?(?=\r?\n|$)
```

It will match everything between line endings (or start/end of document), which does not contain `:\d\s` in it.

- `(?:^|\r?\n)` matches the document start or a line start (UNIX and Windows line endings allowed) in a non-matching group `(?:)`.
- `(?!.*?:\d\s.*?).*?` matches everything except `.*?\:\d\s.*?`.
- `(?=\r?\n|$)` marks a positive lookahead for a line-ending `\r\n` or a document ending `$`. The positive lookahead is necessary, because the line ending would otherwise already be matched by the first part of the regex. Essentially, it would skip every second line, if this part would be matching too (overlapping is not possible in regular regex).

**Here is an example in JavaScript:**

```js
var regex = /(?:^|\r?\n)(?!.*?:\d\s.*?).*?(?=\r?\n|$)/g;
var text = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML; // read the line of the HTML snippet (easier to write lines in HTML);
var match = text.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  line:1 abc123abc123
  line: abc123abc123
  line:3 abc123abc123
  line:4abc123abc123
  line:5 abc123abc123
  line6 abc123abc123
  lineabc123abc123
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in N++. It finds only one instance, and it's not even the desired one o_0 just the last line.

Comment: @AlCrow It works for me in Notepad++, just copy my example lines into a new file, search for the complete regex `(?:^|\r?\n)(?!.*?:\d\s.*?).*?(?=\r?\n|$)` and it matches 4 lines. I had to disable the checkbox though (`.` finds `\r` and `\n`).

Comment: Thanks, it works with unchecked box. Can mark only one solution though, sorry.